# Iterate JSON array and use the Name value to identify a TextView Android

Tags: android, json, loops, variables

I am stuck. I receive a JSON string from a server. I load this into a JSON array called allTheArray.
I now want to iterate through the array and pull name/value pairs out. This I can do.
For each Name in the array I have a corresponding TextView in my layout. For ease of remembering!
I now want to iterate through the array and place the correct value in the correct TextView.
pseudo code.

```
For I =0 to length
Name is get name from allTheArray
Value is get value from allTheArray
TextViewWithTheAboveName.setText=Value
Next
```

Is this possible? In PHP you can use $$variable name etc. I cannot get my head round this. Any suggestions please.

```
button_clearWCC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String TAG ="JSONWALK";
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for(int i = 0; i<allTheArray.names().length(); i++){
                    try {
                        String key=allTheArray.names().getString(i);
                        String value = allTheArray.getString(key);
//the key string is the name of the TextView
//I know I have just set the key to be a string but is there anyway I can use that to define which //TextView I change.
                        key.setText(value)

                        Log.i(TAG, "key = " + key + " value = " + value);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should probably use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).

Comment: How do you store your `TextView`s, you could put them in a `HashMap<String, TextView>` to identify each `TextView` with a string key.

Answer (score 0):

So this was how I solved it.. no idea about overheads or efficiencies but it worked for me. Effectively get the id of the TextView using the key. Then create a TextView t for that id and then use that to empty the cell or add value to cell. This may have implications elsewhere but not found them yet.

```
button_clearWCC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String TAG ="JSONWALK";
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clearing all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for(int i = 0; i<allTheArray.names().length(); i++){
                    try {
                        String key=allTheArray.names().getString(i);
                        String value = allTheArray.getString(key);
//this bit solved it
                        int id = getResources().getIdentifier(key, "id", getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(id);
                        t.setText("");
//end of this bit solved it
                        Log.i(TAG, "key = " + key + " value = " + value);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```